# Zsync download problem

Tags: downloads, zsync

When the zsync downloading a file, sometimes the connection may stuck forever and don't continue for it. Although I can cancel it out, and restart the terminal to continue my downloading task. But it's not a perfect solution for this as it may occur again after approximately 30 minutes. Is it a server-side or my connection problem?

Comment: just stalk it when it stuck. you can use nethogs and monitor for network monitor . so that we can came to a conclusion that, Its hanged.